# iterate through nested dict to get data

Tags: python, dictionary

I have data in below format and I need to get list of keys with same error code and their count of PC's having same error code in python.

```
{'PC1': {'error': 'NOT_ENOUGH_RAM'},
'PC2': {'error': 'POWER_FAILURE'},
'PC3': {'error': 'POWER_FAILURE'}}
```

for example : Output should be like below :

'POWER_FAILURE', ['PC2','PC3'] , 2
'NOT_ENOUGH_RAM', ['PC1'] , 1

Comment: use a `collections.default_dict({})`

Comment: The count is just contained in the `O(1)` (for a list) operation `len`, so it's not necessary to add it to your result.

Answer (score 1):

Using dict.setdefault and a simple loop could work:

```
status = {'PC1': {'error': 'NOT_ENOUGH_RAM'},
'PC2': {'error': 'POWER_FAILURE'},
'PC3': {'error': 'POWER_FAILURE'}}

error = {}

for k,v in status.items():
    error.setdefault(v['error'],[]).append(k)
```

As Kraigolas says in the comments, recording the length of each list is counter-productive, you can calculate it when you print

e.g.

```
print([(k,v,len(v)) for k,v in error.items()])
```